I cannot understand the way these questions were solved
I was going through the mcqs of my physics book and i stumbled upon this pair of questions.
Source of images: vaia.com
1.Figure gives a snapshot of a wave traveling in the direction of positive xalong a string under tension. Four string elements are indicated by the lettered points. For each of those elements, determine whether, at the instant of the snapshot, the element is moving upwards are?
Here is the way the qestion was solved.

Figure b gives the displacement of a string element located at, say, x=0 as a function of time. At the lettered times, is the element moving upward or downward or is it momentarily at rest?

I get the way first problem is solved.
But i cannot understand why second one cannot be solved the same way.
They used slope method for the second question but did not for the first one.
Why is that and how does it make difference?

What is the question in your second picture?

Please use a descriptive title. "I cannot understand the way these questions were solved" is not helpful for potential respondents to evaluate if they may have the necessary expertise to answer a question.

You do see that the horizontal axis is x in figure a and t in figure b? That is, figure a is a picture of the string at two instants. Figure b is the history of the origin over time. It looks like it is also the history of some other point as well.
In figure a, if you want to know where a point is later, you look at the second snapshot. You can see if it is higher or lower.
In figure b, if you want to know where the origin is later, you look at the graph at a later time. That is, you look farther to the right.
